# iOS fetchRequest using sort descriptor on modified keys

Tags: ios, sorting, fetch

I have entities with string properties, call it "option" (entity.option is a string). I want to execute a fetch request but I want to compare the float values of "option".

For example, if I have entity1.option = "10" and entity2.option = "5", I want entity2 to be before entity1 after the sort. Sorting by the string values would put entity1 before entity2 since "1" comes before "5".

How can I set up an NSSortDescriptor to do this? I read that compare blocks do not work with fetch requests so can I modify the key used somehow? That is, suppose I create my sortDescriptor via

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:]
```

Instead of using my property of @"option" as the key, can I do something like @"[option floatValue]"?

EDIT:

I just tried creating a category for NSString that implements a compare method to do what I want. However, even though my code compiles, it fails at run time saying that the compare method I implemented is not a valid selector. I've imported my NSString category into my controller that makes the fetch request but it doesn't work still. I also tried importing the NSString category into my entity that I want to use it but still no luck.

Will this method of using a category not work or am I just not importing the NSString category into the right place?